# is it more efficient to read a big file with multiple lines into a string, or directly read the lines from file one a time?

Tags: python, performance, file, memory, io

I have a text file with 7000 lines of text. (which may not be much in the grand scheme of what our computer can do...). I want to parse the lines into an array.

Just wondering if it would be more memory efficient to directly work with each line of the file directly into the array, or read the entire file into a string, and simply split the string?

example 1:

```
text_file_string = open("big_file.txt", "r")
for line in text_file.split('\n'):
   array.append(line)
```

example 2:

```
with open("big_file.txt","r") as file:
  list = file.readlines()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#module-timeit or print time.now to find the time elapsed.

Comment: The 2nd version would be more performant (use the `timeit` module as mentioned), also the 1st version (in its current state) is not correct. Also, don't use `list` as a variable name, since its a builtin already.

Comment: Do not ask us speculative questions.  Run a timing test to get your answer.  If you have some problem understanding the results, *then* you might have a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: The good question is *how you consume the array?*. If it can be consumed as an iterator is useless to store on an array and iter over lines will be O(1) memory consumption, On the other hand the second one is the best